# Complex Rails Ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a ordered list of results from the following (simplified) table:

```
create_table "evaluations", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "completed_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
end
```

I want to order by `completed_at` (DESC) if `completed_at` is set (not null).  If `completed_at` is null, I want order by `created_at` (DESC).

Is there a way to do this with Rails 3 through the model?

I am using sqlite on my local machine but pg on the server (I will be switching to pg on both soon.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question, but I am not sure it is the most Rails 3 elegant.  Happy if there is a better way!

```
Evaluations.order("CASE WHEN completed_at IS NULL OR THEN created_at ELSE completed_at END DESC")
```